# Hudson build success, but Watir test suite has errors or failures

Tags: hudson, watir

Does anyone know a way to send notification when a Watir test suite run from Hudson contains errors or failures?

Hudson successfully runs the Watir test suite, so considers it a pass, but the actual Watir test cases may have failed...  I would like to either send out notification or get the Hudson build to show as a failure.

Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to provide more data, like relevant code and Hudson setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into parsing the console output, I found the [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) does what I am looking for.

Easy to set up. I installed it configured in the Hudson System Configuration as described and added a simple parsing rules file like below, and it works perfectly.

```
# match line starting with 'Error:'
error /^Error:/
# match line starting with 'Failure:'
error /^Failure:/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this approach,

- Configure the **Hudson** in  such a way that the console output of the **Watir** execution is stored/copied to the server.
- Now if the text **"`Failure`"** occurs in the output then send out a **failure** email notification using appropriate Hudson Configuration.

There above approach is established using **Jenkins**, hope it can also be done in **Hudson**.

Comment: ...this led me to the solution.  I started looking into parsing the output as you suggested and found the Log Parser Plugin.